# How to upload multiple images to server in html

Tags: html, image-uploading

I had the code

```
<form id="styleImageForm1" method= "post" action="../imageUpload/productStyle.json" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="my-element1" name="commonsMultipartFile" value="" multiple />
</form>
```

Only first image which gets selected is uploaded, not all images. My question is how does multiple image uploading works?
Does it take all images at once or one by one image to send to server.

Answer (score 0):

With `[]` into the name field it create an array where you can see all files to upload
Try this code:

```
<form id="styleImageForm1" method= "post" action="../imageUpload/productStyle.json" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="my-element1" name="commonsMultipartFile[]" value="" multiple />
</form>
```

Comment: Still only single image is uploaded. But thanks for your answer

Comment: If you print you $_POST array? Or try to insert many input type file dynamically @vivek